# Insert the same product description with a MYSQL query in Magento 1.7.2

Tags: php, mysql, sql, magento, magento-1.7

Hi to all programmers out there!

I have created 1000 products with a script but without a description.

I would like to insert the same product description in all of them with a MYSQL query.

(I think that table: Catalog_product_entity_text stores the description of a product)

**Could you tell me the query to INSERT the same product description in all of my Products 
in MYSQL?**

Comment: without knowing the table, it would be something like:

----update Catalog_product_entity_text set description = "your description" where 1----

you will have to check the name of the columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inserting data directly into MYSQL tables in magento is considered dangerous due its EAV structure and all the data filtering involved, best method would be to create a shell script inside magentoroot/shell  and save all the descriptions there, the following code snippet might help

```
require_once 'abstract.php';


class Mage_Shell_ProductUpdate extends Mage_Shell_Abstract
{


public function run()
{
     $productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
     foreach($productCollection as $product) {
        $product->load();
        try {

           $product->setDescription('YOUR DESCRIPTION');
           $product->save();

        } catch(Exception $e) {
            print "\n{$e->getMessage()}\n";
        }
     }

}
}
$shell = Mage_Shell_ProductUpdate();
$shell->run();
```

Comment: i will try this!Hope it succed.Thank you very much